# How can I make a 50mH inductor/coil that can stand up to 3A current to be used as a DC inductive load?

Tags: inductor, inductance, coil, electronic-load, inductance-measurement

It will be used to simulate an inductive load for a DC output.

Comment: Can you give some info about the application?

Comment: I will use it as a part of ohmic inductive load for a THREE-PHASE BRIDGE Type Controlled Rectifier Circuit for educational representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start winding some magnet wire. Well, *a lot* of wire unless you use a magnetic core.
If it's for one-off project I'd simply buy one off the shelf, unless your time is free (i.e. you have time to waste winding a coil without proper equipment). For a production run either choose an off the shelf and have it quoted for quantity or ask for a custom part; coils and transformers are routinely made on specification.

For reference: https://www.digikey.it/it/products/detail/hammond-manufacturing/195R10/455491 is a real world 50mH 10A inductor, for AC load. Iron laminated core, with ferrites probably it would be somewhat smaller.

Anyway for educational purposes read this http://info.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Workshop/advice/coils/ (it assumes you *have* a winding machine at your disposal)